# How to get back to the app programmatically after sending sms in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

For sending **sms** using below code:

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
 smsIntent.putExtra("address","125445888");
 smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","test");
 smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
```

Currently it is working fine, but there is no **documentation** available on '**exit_on_sent**'.
So, Is '**exit_on_sent**' has any limitations? If Yes, What is another approach to get your **app** back after sending **SMS**?

Comment: What is current behavior? Does it stay on SMS app?

Comment: no it is returning back to app. But I want to check with other approach too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything in the documentation. As far as I know

**Limitation:**

It does not call `onActivityResult`, but it goes back to the caller app.

**Alternative:**

What I know is the only alternative is to go back manually.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code to send sms:

```
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if(smsMgr != null){
            PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    new Intent(), 0);
            smsMgr.sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "some text", sentIntent, null);
        }
```

for this you should have persmission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```